# How do I insert value of field with a shared name into MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a handful of fields with a shared name.

I want to insert whichever one has data (or a value).  only one field with shared name is being shown at a time with jquery show and hide.

I tried making the name the same in each field like so:

```
mailer_type
```

I tried making it an array like so:

```
mailer_type[]
```

I tried making it an array like so:

```
mailer_type[mt]
```

to grab the post data I tried this:

```
$mailer_type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mailer_type']));
```

to grab the post data I tried this:

```
$mailer_type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mailer_type[]']));
```

to grab the post data I tried this:

```
$mailer_type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mailer_type[mt]']));
```

to grab the post data I tried this:

```
$mailer_type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mailer_type']['mt']));
```

to insert the data into database it's always the same.  haven't tried different things:

```
mysql_query("INSERT jobs SET mailer_type='$mailer_type' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

each time I submit the form, either nothing goes into the table column, or a 0 goes into the table column.  the real value of the field is not being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$mailer_type = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mailer_type']));`

Rather than post, see whether that gets the post data.

Comment: tried that with the names of the form fields being different ways, and it didn't work either time.  mailer_type, mailer_type[], mailer_type[mt]